# PHP server spawned from Node.js is unreachable: ECONNREFUSED

Tags: php, node.js

I have a Node.js program that [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) a PHP built-in server.

I access the PHP server from my Node.js program using the [SuperAgent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent) module.

Everytime, I get the `ECONNREFUSED` error: the PHP server is unreachable. BUT: if I start manually the PHP server (using the same port), the Node.js program is able to access it.

Why the PHP server is unreachable when spawned from a Node.js process? I've tried everything but nothing worked: set `options.detached` to `true`, set `options.stdio` to `ignore`, used a `setTimeout` to ensure the PHP server has enought time to start, etc.

I'm on Windows 10, using Node.js 6.4.0.
The code used is available here: https://github.com/aquafadas-com/gulp-php-minify/blob/master/lib/minifier.js

Comment: 99% it's a user thing, what user do you start manually and what use for node? from my experience, if I run node as admin (I mean, open console as admin) and use npm it works better, because, for example, you can't create symlinks on windows if you're not an admin, and node modules like to use symlinks

Comment: Not an answer, but what are you using the built in server for? Its only intended for development, and runs with a single (blocking) thread.

Comment: @Steve The program is a Gulp.js plugin that minifies PHP code. So, I need a temporary PHP server (usually, its lifetime does not exceed one minute), not a full web server.

Comment: why do you need a webserver at all? Why not use php cli

Comment: Used the CLI, but performance was awful (see [v0.1.x](https://github.com/aquafadas-com/gulp-php-minify/blob/v0.1.2/lib/php_minifier.js) of the project) ! I didn't succeed to make a "daemon" using the CLI, so I spawned a PHP process for EVERY file processed by Gulp. Using this technique, the program was 30x slower !!!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334673/edit-clearly-violating-my-answer-voted-approve-by-reviewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was finally a bug in my code :(

When I launched the PHP server manually, I served the "/web" directory. But when inspecting the spawned process, I saw that the "/lib/web" directory was served (and this folder does not exists).

Replacing the statement `path.join(__dirname, 'web')` by `path.join(__dirname, '../web')` solved the problem.